# MongoDB aggregation sort documents by value inside array on position where array has specific value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We are looking for a way to sort the documents by a value which is in an array inside the document. The special thing is that we only want to sort by the value where another property has a specific value.

This is how our documents look like:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  elements: [
    {
      key: 'locationName',
      value: 'A value'
    },
    {
      key: 'address',
      value: 'Somewhere over the rainbow'
    },
  ],
},
{
  _id: '2',
  elements: [
    {
      key: 'address',
      value: 'Far far away'
    },
    {
      key: 'locationName',
      value: 'Another value'
    },
  ],
},
{
  _id: '3',
  elements: [],
}
```

In this case we want to sort the documents by the location name value, which is in `elements.$.key === 'locationName'`.

After playing around with `$unwind` and `$match` we were able to sort the documents - but with unwinding the array and match by `key === 'locationName'` the last document in the example would be "deleted" because the match failed for this document. But of course we want also to list the documents where no locationName is given. The other problem was that when we were using `$unwind` the other values inside the elements array will be removed if there is no locationName as key - so the `key: address` will be removed and the returned documents will have an object instead of an array which looks like this:

```
{
  _id: '1',
  elements: {
    key: 'locationName',
    value: 'A value'
  },
},
{
  _id: '2',
  elements: {
    key: 'locationName',
    value: 'Another value'
  },
}
```

So our idea was to create a new field in the aggregation which contains the `locationName`. We know that there is the `$addFields` operation but in our case our mongodb version is too low (we are using 3.2) so we would like to find a solution without `$addFields`.

We are not sure if this is possible what we want to do or if this is impossible with our current mongoDB version. Maybe one of you have an idea how to solve this?